# Python code (video processing), NodeJs server and Firebase Storage

Tags: node.js, firebase, video, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I want to build Video Processing Server with NodeJs.

If I upload a video to server, then server send me modified video.

I have Python code for processing videos.

I want to use Firebase storage for upload and download because of scalability and safety.

Now I think the steps should be as below.

1. Client upload video to Firebase Storage
2. Client send the path of video to NodeJs server
3. NodeJs server download video from Firebase Storage.
4. NodeJs server run Python code on the video by PythonShell.
5. NodeJs server upload a modified video to Firebase storage.
6. NodeJs server send path of the modified video for response of step2's req to Client.
7. Client download modified video from Firebase storage

Am I right??
How can I simplify the steps??

I saw there is Firebase function, but it seems only work with javascript not python...

Comment: Why first upload to Firebase? Why not upload to node and python common server first? Once edited upload to firebase and then return URL.

Comment: And which Firebase function is only available in Python not on Nodejs?